# UNION ALL not combining rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, union-all

I have this table called "valores_indices" where it imports stocks values every 1 hour, I need to get the values from each monitored stock at 8am and 6pm, those being respectively my "vlrAberto" and "vlrFechado" selects
I don't get why these are not merging, I've done it before, any help would be appreciated since I'm running out of ideas, I've tried to nest it without any luck

```
SELECT
    i.descricao as cotacao,
    m.quantidade as qtdComprada,
    m.valor as vlrUnitario,
    (m.valor * m.quantidade) as valorCompra,
    v.valor as vlrAberto,
    0 as vlrFechado,
    v.data as data
FROM
    movimento_indices m
    LEFT JOIN indices i ON i.idindice = m.idindice
    LEFT JOIN valores_indices v ON v.idindice = m.idindice
WHERE
    v.hora IN ('08:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    i.descricao as cotacao,
    m.quantidade as qtdComprada,
    m.valor as vlrUnitario,
    (m.valor * m.quantidade) as valorCompra,
    0 as vlrAberto,
    v.valor as vlrFechado,
    v.data as data
FROM
    movimento_indices m
    LEFT JOIN indices i ON i.idindice = m.idindice
    LEFT JOIN valores_indices v ON v.idindice = m.idindice
WHERE
    v.hora IN ('18:00')
```

EDIT

This is what I get

[image]

This is the expected result

[image]

Comment: Merge how? Post sample data and expected results.

Comment: You cannot merge non identical values.

Comment: @forpas See EDIT for sample data and expected results

Comment: @user12975442 No they are not, One column is having zero while the other has a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    i.descricao as cotacao,
    m.quantidade as qtdComprada,
    m.valor as vlrUnitario,
    (m.valor * m.quantidade) as valorCompra,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.hora = '08:00' THEN v.valor END) as vlrAberto,
    MAX(CASE WHEN v.hora = '18:00' THEN v.valor END) as vlrFechado,
    v.data as data
FROM
    movimento_indices m
    LEFT JOIN indices i ON i.idindice = m.idindice
    LEFT JOIN valores_indices v ON v.idindice = m.idindice
WHERE v.hora IN ('08:00', '18:00')
GROUP BY 
    i.descricao,
    m.quantidade,
    m.valor,
    m.quantidade,
    v.data
```

Another option is a lateral join:

```
SELECT
    i.descricao as cotacao,
    m.quantidade as qtdComprada,
    m.valor as vlrUnitario,
    (m.valor * m.quantidade) as valorCompra,
    v.vlrAberto,
    v.vlrFechado,
    v.data as data
FROM
    movimento_indices m
    LEFT JOIN indices i ON i.idindice = m.idindice
    LEFT LATERAL JOIN (
        SELECT 
            MAX(v.valor) FILTER(WHERE v.hora = '08:00') as vlrAberto,
            MAX(v.valor) FILTER(WHERE v.hora = '18:00') as vlrFechado,
            v.data
        FROM valores_indices v
        WHERE v.idindice = m.idindice AND v.hora IN ('08:00', '18:00')
        GROUP BY v.data
    ) v ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: These do not run on our servers, idk if my company's postgres version is old or what :(

Comment: @user12975442: are you getting an error? Please share the entire error message (and indicate whether it comes from the first or second query).

Comment: The first query the problem is the FILTER, when I remove it, it works but doesn't give the desired result (obv reasons haha)

Comment: And the second one I'm not so sure since the software at work doesn't give me much details about error, it just says "syntax error near select", it's a pretty sh*tty software that they use

Comment: @Nimm: OK I updated the first query to not use `FILTER` (although this has been supported in Postgres for ages). It should work for you.

Comment: @Nimm: note that this solution should be much more efficient than `UNION ALL` + aggregation (which requires multiple scans of the table, while my query scans the table only once).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much into PostGreSql but in SQL Server this is how you do it, Give it a try.

```
SELECT cotacao, qtdComprada, vlrUnitario, valorCompra, SUM(vlrAberto) vlrAberto, SUM(vlrFechado) vlrFechado, data FROM (
SELECT
    i.descricao as cotacao,
    m.quantidade as qtdComprada,
    m.valor as vlrUnitario,
    (m.valor * m.quantidade) as valorCompra,
    v.valor as vlrAberto,
    0 as vlrFechado,
    v.data as data
FROM
    movimento_indices m
    LEFT JOIN indices i ON i.idindice = m.idindice
    LEFT JOIN valores_indices v ON v.idindice = m.idindice
WHERE
    v.hora IN ('08:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    i.descricao as cotacao,
    m.quantidade as qtdComprada,
    m.valor as vlrUnitario,
    (m.valor * m.quantidade) as valorCompra,
    0 as vlrAberto,
    v.valor as vlrFechado,
    v.data as data
FROM
    movimento_indices m
    LEFT JOIN indices i ON i.idindice = m.idindice
    LEFT JOIN valores_indices v ON v.idindice = m.idindice
WHERE
    v.hora IN ('18:00')) temp GROUP BY cotacao, qtdComprada, vlrUnitario, valorCompra, data;
```

Comment: It worked!  A few rows still present 0 as a value but most of them are combined now. I'll have to validate the values now

Comment: The ones with 0 is when the task failed to get the data from stocks, stonks!
Thank you so much, I tried to do what you did I just didn't use that temp before my group by